# Mysql search and remove with regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have been consulted to help with a hacked database which has had lots of link injection in thousands of rows.

The basic format of the link injection appears to always be as follows:

```
<a href="http://SOME-RANDOM-LINK-HERE.com/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#676c6c">SOME RANDOM TEXT HERE</a>
```

Essentially I need to delete ALL A tags that contain a style attribute of `text-decoration:none;color:#676c6c`

I am looking for the fastest solution. Whether it be regular expressions or something else, any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please give an example of exactly what you want to delete.

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser and iterate over elements, removing those that are not desirable? Doing this with a regular expression usually leads to very bad outcomes. This is better done in a scripting language like PHP than in MySQL directly.

Comment: Why not simply restore from backup? You should consider the application and database compromised, restore from backup, and then patch.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no backups.

Comment: The thing is, are there any hyperlinks in the database that are legit, or you want to remove them all? If all, then you could use REPLACE and get everything from `<a` to `</a>`.

Comment: Fred -ii- , yes there are legitimate hyperlinks however the ones that are spam are identified with the specific style attribute of "text-decoration:none;color:#676c6c"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for injected links using this regex.

**Regex:** `<a .*? style="text-decoration:none;color:#676c6c".*?>.*?<\/a>`

This will look for `<a></a>` with `style="text-decoration:none;color:#676c6c"`. This won't touch other links.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO1eH3/1)**

You should also check this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)** on how to do replace in MySql.